# Building staircase from first floor to the attic with a Dorm window for headroom. Large 40 x 12 attic space.

Tags: remodeling

I want to add a staircase by taking space from the living room for the staircase then adding a large dorm window space to give headroom (gable roof) at the top of the stairs so that I can enter the main area of the attic.

I have a 16ft x 19ft living room in a one story house with a basement. House build in 1929 and has a large attic. Not counting the 6 ft down slope space on each side of the gable roof, I have 40ft x 12ft down the center of a gable roofed attic.

The 16ft sidewall on the right side will be the support wall where the stair railing will be mounted. I am remodeling queen.

How to I build the staircase?

Also, The dorm window space will be built in the 6ft deep down slope. I am estimated that I need about a 5 to 6ft wide window space. Your thoughts here?

Thanks
Monica

Comment: What is your question? SE is a question-answer site, and not a discussion forum. You need to pose a single, very specific question to fit our format.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to bring in an expert to evaluate the building structure to see if what you have in mind if even feasible. There is little chance that your short text about your intentions can provide the detail needed to determine feasibility. Also since the area is probably enclosed from below at the present time pictures would likely not help too much here either.

Some things to consider:

Adding a 5 or 6 foot wide dormer opening into an existing sloped roof will likely require some major re-work of the roof structure in that area.

Many houses with attics have minimally sized ceiling joists that may not come close to supporting a floor from above. It is likely that some new joists between supporting walls will be needed to make the space safe but that could reduce your existing headroom to too much.

There are a lot of old style constructions that had center support posts under the rafters in the attic. If  your space is like that you may not be able to legitimately remove them.